# Is there a variable available for user defined category trigger word?

Tags: categories

I'm in a situation where **I have to** build a url like :

```
{path='template/group/category/{category_url_title}'}
```

Now, if someone changes the *category* trigger word in the control panel, this URL will lead to a 404. I wonder if there is any undocumented? variable that would give me the category trigger word, without enabling php in the template ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't, but maybe you don't need one or, if you really need, you can create one.

The [docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#path) says:

> The category designation information will automatically be added to the end of the URL so that the target page will know which category to display.

So, inside of a {categories} variable pair, the necessary info will be added and you don't need to worry about it.

If you still want to prevent the user from changing this, you can [override this setting](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#reserved-category-word) on the `config.php` file:

```
$config['reserved_category_word'] = 'category';
```

Now, this setting can't be changed on Admin › Channel Administration > [Global Channel Preferences](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/global_channel_preferences.html#category-url-indicator). But it can still be changed on Admin > System Administration > [Config File Editor](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/config_editor.html).

If you still need the variable, you can create it. Back on the `config.php`, after you set the `$config['reserved_category_word']`, add this before `// END EE config items`:

```
/**
 * @see  https://gist.github.com/464756
 */
global $assign_to_config; // Make this global so we can add some of the config variables here

// make sure our global vars config exists
if(!isset($assign_to_config['global_vars']))
$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array();
```

And them create your variable:

```
$assign_to_config['global_vars']['cv-category_word'] = $config['reserved_category_word'];
```

I prefixed the variable with `cv-` to make it easier to remember where it was set, a Config Variable, but you can use the name you prefer.

You can access this variable on your templates: `{cv-category_word}`.

Remember that you can always set which parts of the CP the user can have access to.

Comment: Or you can make one global variable in index.php  ``{reserved_cat_word}`` and use that in your templates. When the word changes, you only have to change the global assigned variable once.

Comment: @GDmac, this is almost the same I said. I believe that to keep these variables on the `config.php` is better than on the `index.php`: to keep all stuff in one place. But if you disagree, feel free to improve the answer. Your English is probably better than mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you're creating this URL inside of a `{categories}` loop - in which case you simply need to do this:

```
{path="template/group"}
```

This will output **/template/group/category_trigger/category_url_title**.

Comment: I'm not inside a regular categories tag, hence this specific question.